# How can I send all calls to voicemail during "busy" calendar events?

Tags: calls, calendar, automation, voicemail

Basically I'd like to have something that auto sends calls to voicemail when I'm "busy", and possibly as a bonus, send a reply text as well.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: See also: [How to enable silent mode during calendar events?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/21937)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few apps that can do this for you, or at least some of these things. One I saw on [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/agent-automates-common-android-tasks-saves-your-batter-1445139320) yesterday is *[Agent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tryagent)*.

> Agent is a combination automation tool and personal assistant that will silence your phone during meetings, remember where you parked, auto-respond to texts and phone calls while you're driving, and more, all so you don't have to.